# Concatenate two lists of strings in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to access the data from an API for the Euro 2020 soccer championship:
I ended up by having two lists:

```
match = []
home_teams = ('Wales', 'Italy', 'Netherlands', 'Belgium')
away_teams = ('Denmark', 'Austria', 'Czech Republic', 'Portugal')
```

In the end I would like to have the list `match` to have these elements:

```
['Wales - Denmark', 'Italy - Austria', 'Netherlands - Czech Republic', 'Belgium -Portugal']
```

I've tried to iterate through both lists and append the element to the match lists but of course this is not working and now I understand why, but in the end how can I come up with something to solve my case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `zip` the two collections of teams together:

```py
home_teams = ('Wales', 'Italy', 'Netherlands', 'Belgium')
away_teams = ('Denmark', 'Austria', 'Czech Republic', 'Portugal')
match = [' - '.join([h,a]) for h,a in zip(home_teams, away_teams)]
```

Output as requested

Comment: Amazin, this indeed did the trick for me ;) Many thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can use a comprehension + `zip`:

```
 match = [ home + ' - ' + away for home,away in zip(home_teams, away_teams)]
```